# JMeter Same User On Each Iteration - Can we use this functionality with HTTP Cookie manager and HTTP Cache Manager

Tags: cookies, jmeter, cache-control

I have created one simple JMeter script in V5.3. There I am using HTTP cookie and cache manager in test plan level and I am selecting both clear cookie/cache on each iteration. Under that I have kept one thread group with a HTTP sampler inside it. In the thread group level I have selected "Same User On Each Iteration" and executed it for 1 thread and 3 loop counts.

Will it behave as the same user in all the 3 iterations or treat them as different users as we have already selected clear cookie and cache on each iteration from test plan level?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Why would you do mutually exclusive things?

- If you want cookies and cache to **remain** between Thread Group iterations - **tick** `Same user on each iteration box`
- And vice versa, if you want to clear cookies and cache - don't tick this box

Going forward:

- If you tick `Same User On Each Iteration` box on Thread Group level and `Clear cache each iteration` box on HTTP Cache Manager level the HTTP Cache Manager will **override** the thread group settings

More information:

- [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [Introducing JMeter 5.2!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2)